# react-datepicker. Is it possible to make the left and right calendars in the DatePicker move independently

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-datepicker

I have a date range picker, and the problem is when I change the month right calendar always month + 1 [DatePicker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odQBu.png).

```
<DatePicker
          renderCustomHeader={(headerProps) => <DatePickerHeader {...headerProps} />}
          disabledKeyboardNavigation
          onChange={onChange}
          startDate={startDate}
          endDate={endDate}
          maxDate={new Date()}
          selectsRange
          inline
          monthsShown={2}
          calendarClassName="custom-datepicker"
          renderDayContents={renderDayContents}
        />
```

**Is there any way to separate them?**

eg left(Dec 2022) - right (Feb 2023). But if left month & year === right month & year, the right month should be left month + 1.